# This Worksheet Sum Function is very slow - Ideas to speed it up?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following sum function that requires lots of time to give an output:

```
Sub Sum_multiple_columns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim destinationLastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim TotalCoverage As Double
    Dim rng As Range, MyResultsRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Const FirstCol As Long = 12 ' "L"
    Const LastCol As Long = 24 ' "X"
    Const TotalCoverageColumn As Long = 9
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    destinationLastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To destinationLastRow
        Set MyResultsRng = ws.Range("K" & i)
        For Each cell In MyResultsRng
            Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, FirstCol), ws.Cells(i, LastCol))
            TotalCoverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.Value)
            With MyResultsRng
                .Value = TotalCoverage
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Font.Color = RGB(40, 101, 156)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Size = 9
                .Font.Name = "Calibri"
                .NumberFormat = "0.00"
             End With
        Next cell
    Next i
End Sub
```

In your opinion, how could I speed up this code which is intented to sum values from column L to X and put the result into column K for every row in the list.

Thank you

Comment: Just sum the columns, so instead of doing A 1 to 20, b 1 to 20, just use sum(a1:b20)

Comment: `TotalCoverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.Value)` should be `TotalCoverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)`

Comment: Your problem certainly does not come from summing. It comes mostly from the range formatting. Since the format is the same, you should do this operation at the end, at once for **all the range**. Then isn't `MyResultsRng` a single cell? If yes, why iteration for a single cell?

Comment: Thanks all so far, I edited my code with your suggestions but this is still a bit slow. Do you think I can translate this code into something else?

Comment: Where did you tried my suggestion regarding the real code problem? I mean identic formatting for each cell instead of doing it at once for all the range. Please, try the adapted code I posted. Not tested, but I will guide you if an error will occur...

Comment: What is `TotalCoverageColumn` for?  It does not seem to be being used…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's just skip the loops entirely.

```vb
Sub Sum_multiple_columns()
    Const FirstCol As Long = 12 ' "L"
    Const LastCol As Long = 24 ' "X"
    Const OutputColumn As Long = 11 ' "K"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, OutputRange As Range
    Dim FirstSumRow As Range, FirstSumTarget As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set OutputRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, OutputColumn), ws.Cells(LastRow, OutputColumn))
    Set FirstSumRow = ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, FirstCol), ws.Cells(5, LastCol))
    FirstSumTarget = FirstSumRow.Address(False, True, xlA1, False)

    Dim tmpCalc AS xlCalculation: tmpCalc = Application.Calculation 'Save setting
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Makes things slightly faster
    
    With OutputRange
        .Formula = "=SUM(" & FirstSumTarget  & ")" 'This will fill down automatically
        .Calculate 'Needed because Calculation is currently manual
        .Value = .Value 'Convert the formulae into flat values
        
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.Color = RGB(40, 101, 156)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 9
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With
    
    Application.Calculation = tmpCalc 'Restore setting saved earlier
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `Application.ScreenUpdating = False ` should also be added at the start of the macro ? (see: [Application.ScreenUpdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating)

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub Sum_multiple_columns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, destinationLastRow As Long, i As Long
    
    Const FirstCol As Long = 12 ' "L"
    Const LastCol As Long = 24 ' "X"
    Const TotalCoverageColumn As Long = 9
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    destinationLastRow = ws.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    For i = 5 To destinationLastRow
        ws.Range("K" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range(ws.cells(i, FirstCol), ws.cells(i, LastCol)))
    Next i
    With ws.Range("K5:K" & destinationLastRow)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.color = RGB(40, 101, 156)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 9
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With
End Sub
```

Not tested, but it should work if I did not miss anything...

Comment: Hi thanks a lot guys, the solution provided by Chronocidal is the fastest one.

Comment: @Kurt If you will add some optimization, as `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` 
  `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the code start and make them `True` (respective `xlCalculationAutomatic`) it will be faster. I only wanted to show you where the real problem is...